# How to save the PropertyGrid data into global data structure by C#?

Tags: c#, propertygrid

I tried to use PropertyGrid interface for allowing users type their own custom data which would be saved to their own project file later on. My intention is to save these custom input data to a global data structure first and then put these data from global data structure into the project file. It was not difficult to build PropertyGrid interface by C#. But I have difficulty to get the grid entry data out of the interface and save them to the global data structure. I have searched all possible answers in this website but not quite satisfied with the replies. I wonder if someone could help me out. The snippet codes look like the following:

```cs
[DefaultPropertyAttribute("ProjectID")]
public class AppSettings // PropertyGrid object data
{
    private string projectID = "SS001";
    private string companyName = "Compass Corp.";
    private string clientName = "Event";
    private string projectTitle = "Temp";
    private string projectNumber = "001";
    ......
}    

// PropertyGrid Dialog 
public class PropertyGridDialog : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
    private System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGrid DialogPropertyGrid;

    public PropertyGridDialog()
    {
        DialogPropertyGrid = new PropertyGrid();
        DialogPropertyGrid.Size = new Size(540, 450);
        DialogPropertyGrid.PerformAutoScale();

        this.Controls.Add(DialogPropertyGrid);
        this.Text = "Define Project Information";

        // Create the ProjectInfo class and display it in the PropertyGrid
        AppSettings proinfo = new AppSettings();
        DialogPropertyGrid.SelectedObject = proinfo;
        DialogPropertyGrid.HelpBorderColor = SystemColors.Control;
        DialogPropertyGrid.LineColor = Color.LimeGreen;//Color.BlueViolet; 
        DialogPropertyGrid.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        DialogPropertyGrid.PropertyValueChanged += new PropertyValueChangedEventHandler(this.DialogPropertyGrid_PropertyValueChanged);
    }

     private void DialogPropertyGrid_PropertyValueChanged(object s, PropertyValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ...;  // save data to global data structure

    }
    [STAThread]
    static void Main() 
    {
       Application.Run(new PropertyGridDialog());
    }
 }

 public sealed class GlobalArch  // define the singleton class, Global data 
{
    private static volatile GlobalArch instance;

    private static object syncRoot = new Object();

    private GlobalArch()
    {
        ....
    }
  ...
}
```

In the above codes, I tried to save the PropertyGrid entry data to global data structure, GlobalArch under the DialogPropertyGrid_PropertyValueChanged function but it seems doesn't work plus this function only can save one item at a time. It can not handle all the item entry data from PropertyGrid.I want to know what is good way to save the PropertyGrid input data out of current PropertyGrid class to a global data structure. Most examples I found so far are related to how to build PropertyGrid interface and associate the object data with it. I couldn't find some examples to demonstrate how to save the input data out of interface class to a external file or global data structure. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add "Apply changes" button on which handler you can save all the settings from the property grid. Make it `enabled` in `DialogPropertyGrid_PropertyValueChanged` and disable it when data has been saved

Comment: Hi Aspirin, can you specifically shed me some lights on how to save all the setting from the property grid in my program? Do I need to use PropertyDescriptor class to retrieve the grid data? Is there someone could provide me some examples on this? Thanks.